# Kotlin + Parceler + Realm

Tags: kotlin, realm, parceler

I'm trying to integrate Parceler library in a Kotlin project with Realm, but I'm facing with problems when I try to adapt an entity to Realm and Parcel.

```
@Parcel(implementations = { EventRealmProxy::class.java },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { Event::class.java })
@RealmClass
open class Event : Serializable, RealmObject(){

    open var dislike : Boolean = false
    open var like : Boolean = false
    open var blocked : Boolean = false
    open var visits : Boolean = false

}
```

And this is the error:

```
Error:(13, 19) Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Class<Event>
but Array<KClass<(raw) Any>> was expected
```

I'm trying to find some example of a Class defined with Realm and Parceler in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit. Can you try this?

```
@Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(EventRealmProxy::class.java),
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = arrayOf(Event::class))
@RealmClass
open class Event : Serializable, RealmObject(){

    open var dislike : Boolean = false
    open var like : Boolean = false
    open var blocked : Boolean = false
    open var visits : Boolean = false

}
```

I'm not on my personal computer so i couldn't run code. If it's not working sorry for wasting your time. i'll try to improve my answer when i have time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately doesn't works. These are the errors:   `Error:(11, 27) Only 'const val' can be used in constant expressions
Error:(11, 35) Unresolved reference: EventRealmProxy
Error:(11, 35) An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant
Error:(13, 19) Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Class<Event>> but Array<KClass<(raw) Any>> was expected`

Comment: i edited my answer. you should put your full log to your question to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: This is the error with your las suggestion: `e: /Users/sami/StudioProjects/project/dat-core-android/datcorelibrary/src/main/java/com/reto/datcorelibrary/model/Event.kt: (24, 27): Only 'const val' can be used in constant expressions
e: /Users/sami/StudioProjects/project/dat-core-android/datcorelibrary/src/main/java/com/reto/datcorelibrary/model/Event.kt: (24, 35): Unresolved reference: EventRealmProxy
e: /Users/sami/StudioProjects/project/dat-core-android/datcorelibrary/src/main/java/com/reto/datcorelibrary/model/Event.kt: (24, 35): An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @Parcel(implementations = { EventRealmProxy::class.java },
> ```

should have been

```
@Parcel(implementations = [EventRealmProxy::class.java],
```